# how to display sum of balance/income and expense working with android

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am building an app that handles users incomes and expenses and I have already built the database to save and show every incomes and expenses in listview according to the users actions but now I am almost stuck to continue my app because I don't have idea how to display the overall balance/incomes and expenses like when the user add some $100 amounts and the background need to append with previous balance.

I really appreciate any sample examples and tips

here is my dbhandler class`

```
public class ExpDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// columns of the expenses table
public static final String TABLE_EXPENSE = "expense";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_PAYMENT_METHOD = "payment_method";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE = "date";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPENSE_TIME = "time";

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "expense.db";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

// columns of the Income table
public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "income";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_PAYMENT_METHOD = "payment_method";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_DATE = "date";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_TIME = "time";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_EXPENSE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_EXPENSE + "("
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_AMOUNT + " REAL NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_LOCATION + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_PAYMENT_METHOD + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_EXPENSE_TIME + " TEXT )";

// create table for income
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_INCOME = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_INCOME + "("
        + COLUMN_INCOME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COLUMN_INCOME_AMOUNT + " REAL NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_INCOME_LOCATION + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_INCOME_PAYMENT_METHOD + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_INCOME_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_INCOME_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_INCOME_DATE + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_INCOME_TIME + " TEXT )";

private Context context;

public ExpDbHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_EXPENSE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_INCOME);
        Message.message(context,"ITs Created Successfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Message.message(context,"not created" +e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    try {
        Message.message(context,
                "Upgrading the database from version " + oldVersion + " to "+ newVersion);
        // CLEAR DATA
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EXPENSE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INCOME);
        // AND CALLBACK TO RECREATE A TABLE
        onCreate(db);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Message.message(context,
                "" + e);
    }

}



public ExpDbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

}

and my DataAccessObject that declares ExpenseDAO class

```
public class ExpenseDAO {

private ExpDbHandler mExpDbHandler;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
public static final String TAG = "CompanyDAO";
private Context mContext;
private String[] mAllColumns = {ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_ID, ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_AMOUNT, ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_LOCATION,
        ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_PAYMENT_METHOD, ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_CATEGORY, ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION,
        ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE, ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_TIME};

public ExpenseDAO(Context context) {
    mExpDbHandler = new ExpDbHandler(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    // database open

    try {
        open();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SQLEXCEPTION FOR OPENING DATABASE" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    mDatabase = mExpDbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

}

public void close() {
    mExpDbHandler.close();
}

public ExpenseInfo createExpenseInfo(double amount, String location, String payment_method, String category, String description,
                                     String date, String time) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_AMOUNT, amount);
    values.put(ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_LOCATION, location);
    values.put(ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_PAYMENT_METHOD, payment_method);
    values.put(ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE, date);
    values.put(ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_TIME, time);

    long insertID = mDatabase.insert(ExpDbHandler.TABLE_EXPENSE, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(ExpDbHandler.TABLE_EXPENSE, mAllColumns,
            ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_ID + " = " + insertID, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ExpenseInfo NewExpenseInfo = cursorToExpenseInfo(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return NewExpenseInfo;
}

public List<ExpenseInfo> getAllExpenses() {
    List<ExpenseInfo> listExpenses = new ArrayList<ExpenseInfo>();

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(ExpDbHandler.TABLE_EXPENSE, mAllColumns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        ExpenseInfo expenseInfo = cursorToExpenseInfo(cursor);
        listExpenses.add(expenseInfo);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    //  I need to make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();

    return listExpenses;
}

public List<ExpenseInfo> getExpenseById(long id) {
    List<ExpenseInfo> listExpenseInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(ExpDbHandler.TABLE_EXPENSE, mAllColumns,
            ExpDbHandler.COLUMN_EXPENSE_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        ExpenseInfo expenseInfo = cursorToExpenseInfo(cursor);
        listExpenseInfo.add(expenseInfo);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    //  close cursor
    cursor.close();
    return listExpenseInfo;

}

protected ExpenseInfo cursorToExpenseInfo(Cursor cursor) {
    ExpenseInfo expenseInfo = new ExpenseInfo();
    expenseInfo.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    expenseInfo.setAmount(cursor.getDouble(1));
    expenseInfo.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));
    expenseInfo.setPayment_method(cursor.getString(3));
    expenseInfo.setCategory(cursor.getString(4));
    expenseInfo.setDescription(cursor.getString(5));
    expenseInfo.setDate(cursor.getString(6));
    expenseInfo.setTime(cursor.getString(7));
    return expenseInfo;
}
```

}

My ExpenseInfo class

```
public class ExpenseInfo{

private long mId;
private double mAmount;
private String mLocation;
private String mPayment_method;
private String mCategory;
private String mDescription;
private String mDate;
private String mTime;

public ExpenseInfo(){

}

public ExpenseInfo (double amount, String location, String payment_method,String category, String description, String date,
                    String time){
    this.mAmount=amount;
    this.mLocation=location;
    this.mPayment_method=payment_method;
    this.mCategory=category;
    this.mDescription=description;
    this.mDate=date;
    this.mTime=time;
}

public long getId() {
    return mId;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return mAmount;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return mLocation;
}

public String getPayment_method() {
    return mPayment_method;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return mCategory;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}

public String getDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public String getTime() {
    return mTime;
}

public void setId(long mId) {
    this.mId = mId;
}

public void setAmount(double mAmount) {
    this.mAmount = mAmount;
}

public void setLocation(String mLocation) {
    this.mLocation = mLocation;
}

public void setPayment_method(String mPayment_method) {
    this.mPayment_method = mPayment_method;
}

public void setCategory(String mCategory) {
    this.mCategory = mCategory;
}

public void setDescription(String mDescription) {
    this.mDescription = mDescription;
}

public void setDate(String mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public void setTime(String mTime) {
    this.mTime = mTime;
}
```

}

Comment: Look at listViews adapters and to refresh the data use `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: thank you for your answer and i will try it with my listview adapter which extends to base adapter

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a nice example of displaying items in the list view which you will probably be using.
There are so many ways to display items in list view but the primary part is the list adapter which contains the data.
Considering your approach, you are getting the updated list from your DAO class, you can extend the create a custom adapter by extending BaseAdapter class. [Here's](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92) another example.
After fetching the list from your DAO class, you can update the list in your custom adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged() method of the adapter.

Another approach could be not using DAO at all and use ContentProviders and loaders. I found Content providers and loaders a bit tricky to learn in the beginning but they make life much easier.
I had used them in one of my projects and you can explore it [here](https://github.com/kanishktripathi/TwitterStream). [This](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) is a really nice article on Loaders. I would suggest to know Loaders and Content providers as they are very convenient and maintainable than a DAO and Table to object mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that are whole and exactly true